# In-memory objects index in .NET

Tags: .net

I would like to create a quicksearch in my application.

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class Venue
{
    public virtual string LongName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShortName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Market { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClientEmail { get; set; }
}
```

and I would like to index a set of this (and other) objects.

The idea it that user will type some data into textbox, and "in-memory index" will accept that string, and return all objects that contain searched value in one or more properties.

Is there a out of the box solution in .NET for such a thing? Or library, or whatever?

Thanks

Comment: So `contains`, not `equals` right?

Comment: Lucene.NET should do the trick: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29755/Introducing-Lucene-Net

Comment: Hmm contains or equals. Basically full-text-search on object's string properties and Equals on numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Lucene.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29755/Introducing-Lucene-Net) or even [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net) document database if you want to store the data in relatively cool way - which is by the way based on Lucene.Net. RavenDB implements LINQ driver so you can use LINQ queries accross your collections, and fetch them dynamically. You have indexing support so you can achieve really high performance for your computations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any out of the box solution, but i would do it manually.

```
string input = "whatever";
IEnumerable<Venue> matches = allVenues.Where(v => v.LongName.Contains(input)
                               ||  v.ShortName.Contains(input)
                               ||  v.Market.Contains(input)
                               ||  v.ClientEmail.ToString().Contains(input));
```

Maybe it's fast enough. The advantage is that you don't need any additional resources.